# python3, Value Exception on multiple inputs, correct sequence?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, integer, multiple-instances

Me Beginner on pycharm.

Dont find a answer how check **multiple Integer input**, with **Value Error Exception**.
My Code is that now:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Give first Integer: "))
        num2 = int(input("Give second Integer: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You need Integer!")
```

But there are few issues. Run Code and Output is:

```
Give first Integer: 1
Give second Integer: w
You need Integer!
Give first Integer:
```

Dont know how to rebuild the Code, that the loop begins on num2, when Value false. And also the Cursor is not ready on the input place, for num1, he is blinking on Postion 1 in the Line. **Num1 Exception works**.

In Question:

- If **num2** is not Integer, i need to insert **num1** again. How to only insert **num2** when **num2** is false?
- The Cursor jumps to pos1 in the line of second asking for Input "Give first Integer:". How to let the cursor on the right place, after ":"?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, there might be more pythonic way, but this does it:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Give first Integer: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You need Integer!")
while True:
    try:
        num2 = int(input("Give second Integer: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You need Integer!")
```

Sample output:

```
Give first Integer: R
You need Integer!
Give first Integer: 4
Give second Integer: NO
You need Integer!
Give second Integer: Nope
You need Integer!
Give second Integer: -12
```

---

Approach 2 with one while loop:

```
valid = []
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Give an Integer: "))
        valid.append(num)
        if len(valid) == 2:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("You need Integer!")
num1, num2 = valid
print("The entered integers are: ", num1, num2)
```

Sample output:

```
Give an Integer: NOOO
You need Integer!
Give an Integer: 45
Give an Integer: again?
You need Integer!
Give an Integer: okay
You need Integer!
Give an Integer: 4
The entered integers are:  45 4
```

Comment: its just a second while true loop? haha* and that works ! But cursor is not on input place, if i type it works on the input place...so maybe a editor issue...Thank U

Comment: hey, I just added second approach with one while loop, maybe you'll find it more useful :)

Comment: i see, looks better for me...will try too

Comment: (VALID[]) looks new ...dont need (if len(valid) == 2:)...the last "print" i dont need..its just the exception there are only numbers and no trackball error. its a calculator code
My gist here, ist in german but looks nice for the first time i code - https://gist.github.com/cxbignekoc/fd171c367986f9db36d1d35b4d4a9308